# Finding a freelancing partner for small business

Tags: project-management, outsourcing, group-freelancing

I'm currently freelancing doing mostly front-end development and design; things are going very well, sometimes a little too well... Lately I'm finding myself overbooked, if they are and hold ups along a project its eating away at my time and I'm starting to annoy clients because I'm over stretched!

I'd really like to find another freelancing in the UK who would be willing to partner up and take some load off me. Obviously I'd like to find someone who I could trust, and they would have to have strong skills.

I just haven't got time to go to freelancing sites and do it that way, plus I'm really fussy about good clean consistent code.

Does anyone have any other suggestions for how to find a partner as a freelancer?

Comment: Soliciting freelancers is quite definitely against the scope of this site (regardless of the fact it's not even written down fully yet). I suggest you [edit] your question and try not to make it sound like you're trying to do this.

Comment: I'm a freelancer and have a genuine question about sourcing partners...

Comment: I got that, but I've deleted a bunch of comments that seem to think otherwise.

Comment: Let me point you in the direction of the Professional Contractors Group [link](http://www.pcg.org.uk) who have a forum for this sort of solicitation.

Comment: Read my post about finding the right contractor for your overload is not as easy as it sounds. Best of luck anyway.

Comment: why Hiroto delete comments and edit questions, changing content as he want?! -please take a break!

Comment: @matheszabi - Comments are intended to suggest improvements to a post or seek clarification, not try to land a job, and part of the community's role is to help keep the site on-topic so it thrives. Also, Stack Exchange sites are wiki-like Q&A sites, and editing to improve content is what makes Stack Exchange stand out from forums and such. See the [list of privileges](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) for more details on how you can help as a community member. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Place an advertisement in traditional venues (Online/newspapers).

You aren't going to just stumble upon someone. You will have to seek them out, or ask them to contact you then vet them yourself.

In my experience, looking for people online with a specific skill set simply results in **a lot** of wasted time due to many *thinking* they can do a job they can't. You'll need to get a list of prospective partners, then go over their qualifications just as any employer would.

Answer (score 1):

You can post online or local ads, but if you prefer to work with someone in your country, you can specify it. It's also very different to "partner" with someone or to hire that person as a contractor; you cannot either expect the same kind of loyalty from a contractor you will get from a partner.

**There are a few things you need to consider and that can give you some clues on where you should look for freelancing partners:**

1. **You need to make sure they sign a Non-Disclosure Agreement (NDA)
   with you before the "interview."** Trust is very important but the law
   is what will protect you in these cases. That's why you also benefit from hiring someone in the same country as you. It's also very important to
   add clauses that forbid the contractor or candidate to contact your
   clients. I suggest to be transparent with your clients if you use a
   contractor but this is your personal decision.
2. **You might want to hire someone first and then offer a partnership agreement after testing her/his skills.** This gives you more
   control on the information you're expected to share with them and
   what you prefer to keep for yourself. This is a good investment for you.
3. **If possible, find a partner that is a full-time freelancer as well.**
   The reason is that many freelancers do it as a side job and they
   will always prioritize their full-time job first. It's important to
   find someone who has the same goals as you and understands your
   priorities. They're also usually more reliable than part-time workers.
4. **If you have a potential candidate in mind, go have a look at their
   social media profiles and do a good search online** with any of the
   email addresses you have that belongs to this person, pseudonym,
   interests, etc.  This way you'll learn a lot about the candidate
   his/her level of maturity, understanding of privacy and
   professionalism. That will also help to add important details in
   your contract that could save you a lot of troubles later (eg.
   people posting drunk pictures or saying negative comments about
   their clients online or people with a "Steam" gamer profile with 30hr a week of gaming!)
5. **Ask for a Skype interviews, phone conversations and meetings.** Lot of
   things can be read through body language and the voice tone (eg.
   hesitation)!
6. **If you ever, EVER have a little red light or weird feeling about a
   candidate, listen to your guts instinct and try to not compromise.**
   If you aren't sure of something, do your investigation, don't feel
   uncomfortable to ask questions For example, if the candidate says
   things like "*My wife will help if I can't do all the work...*" This
   is a big NO; you don't want to be stuck with a third party that
   isn't fully part of your NDA and contract.
7. **And of course, ask for references if possible but most of all,
   examples of previous projects.** Do a research such as reverse image
   search or looking in the source code to see if the work is really
   his/hers. Sometimes a nice Wordpress theme might look very good 
   but it's still not really about coding but small code customization. That
   might not be what you need or can't do yourself.
8. **Make sure the terms, payments, mode of payments, number of weekly hours and conditions are agreed on, and
   understood.** As contractors, they should understand that you cannot
   give them 100% of the payment you get yourself simply because of
   your work managing the projects and also the cost of transactions. A
   good number, is to keep at least 30% for yourself and adjust this
   accordingly. If you ever get into partnership with someone else, then that number can change but so is the share of the expenses.
9. **You should tell your contractor or future partner about the kind of
   contract and clients you target.** Some people might not be
   comfortable working on some topics for different reasons (eg. moral
   principles, religious beliefs, previous agreement with their own
   clients, etc.)
10. **You can find freelancers pretty much anywhere and don't limit
     yourself to freelance websites.** In fact you might find a better fit
     in business online groups (eg. LinkedIn), associations, by
     referral, local employment center or by browsing the web. On
     freelancers's sites, a lot of freelancers have their own business
     and enjoy the "freedom" they get there, OR have very rigid terms
     that may not be a good fit for collaboration OR are part-time
     freelancers and not fully invested in their freelance career. A lot of very talented and hard working freelancers are not always "hawking" loud about their skills because... they're busy working or they simply more introvert! You can find these people sometimes by being observant on social media or following their blogs; they could be a friend of a friend for example. Have initiative and take the attitude of a talent seeker.

---

Finally, it's the same as hiring an employee and you have all rights and the tools to make sure you hire someone you'll enjoy working with. You can totally act in the same way as any employer, you can set your requirements as you want. You can start by hiring them as contractors and then offer partnership that should give you more freedom if you change your mind along the way or discover things you don't like about the contractor (eg. bad attitude, late projects, bad quality.)