# Are there platforms to find partners for a startup project?

Tags: freelance-websites, working-from-home, project-management, programmer, outsourcing

I'm starting to ride their own little project, but I would do it with someone else who could like him.  Now I would be doing myself Frontend/ Backend and design, but in many of these things I'm a mess, especially in design.

I wish I could share experience and work, of course being the whole project partners, adventure and future profits (if they got them).

I searched online forum or a place to meet a friend or partner for this, but I have not found any page dedicated to this. Somebody knows?

Thanks for all!

Comment: HI there, welcome to Freelancing.SE! This question is being closed as Primarily Opinion Based due to having no concrete answer available; as well, it's too broad to ask for lists of recommendations, as a good answer would be hard to "accept", which goes against the Q&A model of the Stack Exchange network. For more information, or to learn how to [edit] your question to be acceptable, please drop by [meta] or [chat]. Thanks!

Comment: Canadian Luke is right. You would hear zillion advises on this topic. I suggest you try posting a job on freelancing websites. I have seen such posts there. I have no idea of their outcome.

Comment: It's not an answer about where to find partners specifically but there's some tips about how to select a good partner! http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/661/finding-a-freelancing-partner-for-small-business/3362#3362

Comment: Thank you very much to all, I had not thought that this question could lead to many different answers. I try to be more specific in other questions.
Peter  I'll look nice but seems to want to find a partner, not hire someone
Thanks go-me sure would help a lot.